# how to extends the parent html page on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, extends

```
templates
    | ....a.html
    |.....admin
            |..... index.html
            |..... b.html
```

in google app engine templates, i can use this to extends b.html in index.html:

```
{% extends 'b.html' %}
```

but how to extends a.html in index.html.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one *extends* per template. It's like single inheritance in OOP languages like C# and Java.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437123/putting-a-block-inside-another-in-django) has an answer that will give you some good ideas for laying out your templates and having a good template inheritence scheme